# Autowired Spring Bean is null intermittently

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

We have a really strange issue in our application and exhausted all option for troubleshooting.

We have a Spring container managed repository bean autowired into Spring managed service bean. During the initialization, we can see that the bean a is successfully initialized and autowired into the service class because we can see the line **ClassBServiceImpl initialized and bean a autowired successfully.** printed on the startup logs.

But during the application run time, we intermittently see `NullPointerException`s in `getA()` method. So we added the log to verify whether the autowired bean is `null`. Sure enough we do see the line **a is null. what happened to autowired bean?** printed to the logs.

We are scratching our heads to figure out why a bean that was autowired previously is not found when needed. Would this be a Spring issue or something wrong at the JVM level that is causing the issue? For reference our stack is one Tomcat instance per pod on OpenShift paas

```
public interface IntA {
      //methods
}

@Repository
public class ClassADao implements IntA {

}

public interface IntB {
      //methods
}

@Service
public class ClassBServiceImpl implements IntB {

   @Autowired
   IntA a;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        if(a== null)
            System.out.println("ClassBServiceImpl initialized but the autowiring of bean a has failed.");
        else{
            System.out.println("ClassBServiceImpl initialized and bean a autowired successfully.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<A> getA() {

        try {

            if(a== null){
                System.out.println("a is null. what happened to autowired bean?");
            }
            List<IssSuperUserAgency> listFromDb = 
                    a.getA();
            ///

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //throw exception
        }

        return new ArrayList<>();
    }



}
```

--EDIT --

Adding the actual code for ClassBServiceImpl.

```
@Service("issSuperUserAgencyService")
public class IssSuperUserAgencyServiceImpl implements IIssSuperUserAgencyService{

    @Autowired
    IIssSuperUserAgencyDao superuserAgencyDao;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        if(superuserAgencyDao == null)
            System.out.println("IssSuperUserAgencyServiceImpl initialized but the autowiring of superuserAgencyDao has failed.");
        else{
            System.out.println("IssSuperUserAgencyServiceImpl initialized and superuserAgencyDao autowired successfully.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<IssSuperUserAgency> getAgenciesByUserIdentifier(
            String userIdentifier) {

        try {
            /*
             * TODO - remove this if block in March 2020 release. It is added only for research purpose.
             */
            if(superuserAgencyDao == null){
                System.out.println("superUserAgencyDao is null. what happened to autowired bean?");
            }
            List<IssSuperUserAgency> listFromDb = 
                    superuserAgencyDao.getAgenciesByUserIdentifier(userIdentifier, CONTEXT_DASHBOARD);

            return getSuperUserAgencyList(listFromDb);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogUtils.error("Exception when trying to retrieve agencies list for super user", e);
        }

        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Comment: I doubt that this is the actual code used, but rather a derived and simplified version of it. I suspect your code has some `final` keywords in there, as well as some non public methods etc. So please post real code instead of made up code that looks like the code you are using. Finally I would strongly suggest to not use field injection and switch to constructor injection (which should prevent this).

Comment: @M.Deinum any reason why construction injection would prevent this error? We know for certain that the bean injection is successful because of the log added to init() method.

Comment: Because constructor injection will never allow an object to be constructed in an invalid state as it requires the dependencies. With field injection you can create it without the dependencies, call methods on it, and afterwards inject dependencies. But as stated I doubt that what you shown here is the full picture. I'm certain there are import pieces missing, making it impossible to answer the question.

Comment: What scope does `IIssSuperUserAgencyDao` bean have? If it's not singleton, then it makes sense..

Comment: @jesuisgenial we haven't specified any scope explicitly for the repository bean. It is singleton by default.

Comment: @M.Deinum i have added the complete code for the service class here.

Comment: Try to write a simple test case that reproduce the problem since it seems a "can't happen case".You can mock everything that is not really needed. If you are able to write a unit test post it here so some peaole can work on it. May be you need to use an embedded tomcat to write the unit test

Comment: As stated I strongly suggest to move to constructor based injection, as well as marking the field both `private` and `final`. If then somewhere compilation fails you know you are working with this class in ways it shouldn't, and it should prevent the `null` from being assigned. Basically an `@Autowired` field cannot be `null`, your application will not start if the dependency cannot be resolved. So either you are doing things you shouldn't be doing (create instances yourself)  or methods are invoked before the bean is fully initialized.